# Squid not getting installed in linux mint

Tags: linux, networking

I am a newbie to linux and network programming. My task is to study and configure squid proxy server. I am using Linux mint 15. Tried sudo apt-get install squid
But this is what i get

```
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main squid-langpack all 20120616-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main squid3-common all 3.1.20-1ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main squid3 i386 3.1.20-1ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/universe squid i386 3.1.20-1ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
0% [Working]E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/squid-langpack/squid-langpack_20120616-1_all.deb: 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
```

Please help me out...

Answer (score 0):

try the following 
make sure internet is working in your machine

sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install squid3